# safari browser doesn't ask for microphone permission

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser

I have a website that needs user permission for accessing to microphone.
in chrome, firefox, and edge, everything it's OK. when the user opens the website, the browser asks for permission. but in the safari, this is not happening ( Safari doesn't ask for permission and I cant use microphone )
this is a problem in safari or on my website? or this is natural in safari?

Comment: [It looks like the permission API is not available in safari](https://caniuse.com/#feat=permissions-api). This is probably due to the restrictive nature of apple's products. I'd say try to work around or maybe add a message that says your app is only available on Chrome / Firefox.

Comment: that is a good idea. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

permission API is not available in safari

Comment: what is alternative way of implementing Permission API in Safari?